# Is it possible to realize $ \mathbb{RP}^2 $ as a linear group orbit?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Does there exists a Lie group $ G $ a representation $ \pi: G \to Aut(V) $ and a vector $ v \in V $  such that the orbit
$$
\mathcal{O}_v=\{ \pi(g)v: g\in G  \} 
$$
is diffeomorphic to the real projective plane $ \mathbb{RP}^2 $?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can embed $\mathbb{RP}^2$ into the space $M_3$ of $3\times 3$ matrices via the map which takes a line $[v]$ to the orthogonal projection onto $[v]$:
$$
[v]\mapsto\frac{vv^T}{\|v\|^2}
$$
This gives a diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{RP}^2$ to the space of rank $1$ orthogonal projection operators:
$$
\mathbb{RP}^2\cong\{A\in M_3:\operatorname{rank}(A)=1,\ A^2=A=A^T\}
$$
One can show that this submanifold is an orbit of the linear $O(3)$ action on $M_3$ defined by $O\cdot A=OAO^T$.

Comment: Wow what a fabulous answer thanks so much! Seems like this shows that acting $ O_{n} $ on $ M_{n} $ by conjugation we can always realize $ RP^{n-1} $ as the orbit of rank one orthogonal projections. The representation decomposes into a direct sum of irreps for n=3 as the scalar matrices( trivial irrep) direct sum the antisymmetric matrices (adjoint irrep) direct sum the traceless antisymmetric matrices (dim 5 irrep). And also it seems that $ RP^{n-1} $ can be equivalently realized as the orbit of the diagonal matrix with diagonal $ ((n-1)/n, -1/n, \dots, -1/n) $

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this gives a method for producing any real grassmanian Gr(k,n) as the orbit, with respect to O_n acting by conjugation on M_n, of all rank k orthogonal projections. Also we could take the conjugation action of SO_n and it would work just as well. Also the reason. I brought up that silly diagonal matrix in my previous comment is that it keeps us inside the irrep of traceless antisymmetric matrices and I like staying inside an irrep when possible.

Comment: And this same thing should work for acting SU_n on M_n(C) by conjugation and orbit of rank k hermitian projections should realize the complex grassmanian Gr(k,n) as a linear group orbit inside the real vector space of (traceless using my adjustment) skew hermitian matrices

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Looks correct to me, except you seem to have put "antisymmetric/skew-Hermitian" in place of "symmetric/Hermitian" in your last two comments. More generally, Grassmannians, flag manifolds, and other "collection of subspaces" constructions on a vector space $V$ tend to arise as orbits of conjugation actions on $\operatorname{End}(V)$. This is essentially what (generalized) eigenvectors /eigenspaces are all about. Many of these generalize to arbitrary fields without too much issue.

Comment: Oh oops ya I meant to say symmetric/ hermitian. So wow this generalizes to flag manifolds and generalized flag manifolds/ reductive G mod parabolic subgroup P very cool. I'm totally fascinated thanks so much for the comment and I'm reading more online. Do you think you could give an example of a 3 by 3 matrix whose orbit under a conjugation action by GL_3(R) is the  manifold of complete flags in R^3?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira One can identify each complete flag in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with an ordered triple of orthogonal lines. Given such a triple $(L_1,L_2,L_3)$ we have the flag $(\{0\},L_1,L_1+L_2,L_1+L_2+L_3)$. This correspondence is one-to-one. This means we can identify the complete flag manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the $O(n)$-orbit of$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix}$$where the lines are the eigenspaces, ordered by their eigenvalues. This generalizes straightforwardly to arbitrary flag manifolds.

Comment: Oh I see I see. So any choice of diagonal matrix diag(a,b,b) with $ a \neq b $ will give $ O_3/O_2 \times O_1 \cong RP^2 $ and any choice $ diag(a,b,c) $ with $ a,b,c $ all distinct will give $ O_3/O_1\times O_1 \times O_1 $. Do you happen to know what spherical 3 manifold this is? Is this the smallest prism manifold with eight element fundamental group isomorphic to the eight element quaternion group?

Comment: You're correct that it's diffeomorphic to the spherical manifold $S^3/Q_8$; I'm not sure what else you're asking beyond that.

Comment: that's all I'm asking thanks!